# How do I configure an NFS server to accept all 172.x.x.x mount requests?

Tags: ip, nfs

I added this 172.0.0.0/0 in /etc/exports but i dont know if this will work. Is there some other configuration option that can be used for this?

Comment: 172.0.0.0/0 is invalid. try 172.0.0.0/8

Comment: ty, and 172.0.0.0/16 is valid?

Comment: Yes, @Jancata, 172.0.0.0/16 is valid, but it means only 172.0.X.X unlike 172.0.0.0/8 which would allow 172.X.X.X. To complete this, I'll add that 172.0.0.0/24 would only permit 172.0.0.X. If you're curious, look up CIDR or classless address.

Comment: @jancata 172.16 is a class b network so /16 is valid and /8 invalid. 10. x. x. x is class A and so /8 valid. if you would use /8 you would also match internet traffic instead only lan. so you would expose your nfs services to the internet